# backend user permissions for HR type role

Tags: orocommerce

I'm trying to set up an HR type role, so one of our users can do all the backend user and division management.
Most of it is working apart form two things
When creating the user the Access Settings tab is missing the normal admin user shows it but my HR role does not
[image: full back end user]
[image: my HR USER]

Is there a specific security item we need to add to allow this

Also when I try to create a new business unit under the unit that user belongs to I get a you do not have permission to perform this action message.  For that HR user I have set all the business permissions to business unit
[image: permissions]
Again do I need to set a specific permission to allow this?

Thanks
Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tab is hidden because the new role doesn't have an Organization view permission.